# Need to parse substrings between characters in multiple rows and columns

Tags: python, regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a file (input.file) that looks like:

```
sampleID_001 1/1:1.3:0.1225,0.455,0.4225 1/1:1.3:0.1225,0.455,0.4225 0/0:0.2:0.525,0.055,0.0025
sampleID_002 0/0:0.1:0.9025,0.095,0.0025 0/0:0.1:0.9025,0.095,0.0025 0/0:0.1:0.9025,0.095,0.0025
sampleID_003 0/0:0.3:0.7025,0.295,0.0025 0/0:0.3:0.7025,0.295,0.0025 0/0:0.3:0.7025,0.295,0.0025
```

but I want to extract only the values between the :'s such that the desired output looks like:

```
sampleID_001 1.3 1.3 0.2  
sampleID_002 0.1 0.1 0.1  
sampleID_003 0.3 0.3 0.3
```

Please note, however, that there are many more rows and columns in the actual file to be processed.

I have tried:

```
grep -oP '(?<=from:)*?(?=:)' <<< "input.file" > output.file
sed 's/.*:\(.*\):.*/\1/' input.file > output.file
awk "/:/,/:/ { print }" input.file > output.file
```

the sed command returned only the first instance of 'something between : :', i.e. 1.3. The grep and awk commands did not yield any output

Comment: How is Python involved?

Answer (score 1):

Using space or comma or colon as the field separators:

```sh
awk -F'[ :,]' '{print $1, $3, $8, $13}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Solutions that work with the given input can fail with other input, since it is hard to tell how much spaces and other characters you will encounter. For good control, use `awk` like

```
awk -F ":| " '{print $1 " " $3 " " $6 " " $9}' input.file
```

When you try with `sed` you must  write out every step:

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]*)[^:]*:([^:]*):[^:]*:([^:]*):[^:]*:([^:]*):.*/\1 \2 \3 \4/g' input.file
```

You can shorten the line when you put the first field in colons too, but that would be hard to understand/change/debug:

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]*)/:\1:/;s/:([^:]*):[^:]*/\1 /g' input.file
```

You might prefer taking some small steps:

```
sed 's/ /:/' input.file | cut -d":" -f 1,3,5,7 | tr ':' ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering python is in the tags, I'd do it like this:

```
import re
str = "sampleID_001 1/1:1.3:0.1225,0.455,0.4225 1/1:1.3:0.1225,0.455,0.4225 0/0:0.2:0.525,0.055,0.0025"
s = re.findall('\:(.*?)\:', str)
print("{} {} {} {}".format(str.split(' ')[0], s[0], s[1], s[2]))
```

for each line.